# scala nested looop-inner loop dependent on outer loop

Tags: java, scala, loops

I am relatively  new to Scala. I am started building my skill by writting small programs.
The below code wanted to print the value of `i` in innner loop for each `i` value the inner loop `j` should run `j<=i`.

```
object Displaying {
   def main (args : Array[String]){


     for( i <- 1 to 10)
     {

       for(j<=i )//want to give a cnditation like (j <= i , j++)
       {
           print("")
           print(i)
       }
       print("\n")

     }
  }
}
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.

Thank you so much in advance !!!
HAPPY CODING

Comment: `println(i)` would get you the same output, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost there. Try to change your code this way:

```
for( i <- 1 to 10) {
  for(j <- 1 to i ) { //want to give a cnditation like (j <= i , j++)
    print("")
    print(i)
  }
  print("\n")
}
```